# List commits and files changed under commit

Tags: git, bash, commit, git-commit, git-log

I was wondering if there is a way to view the commit information **and** the files changed in the commit when using grep.

To retrieve the commits when searching for a string in the commit messages I use:

`git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --grep=<SEARCHING_STRING>`

Then I get the commit id and use the following command to get all files changed under a commit:

`git log --oneline --name-only | grep -Eo "\w/.*\.\w+" | sort -u --grep=<COMMIT_ID>`

I'm trying to create a bash script to combine these two commands in only one and retrieve the commits and all files under a commit without success.

Comment: Just add `--name-only` to the first command?

Comment: what prevents you from just using a command like:  git log --all --grep=<COMMIT-ID> --name-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--name-status` flag. Like:

`git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --name-status --grep=<SEARCHING_STRING>`